# SOCK_STREAM VS SOCK_SEQPACKET

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I have read from the PHP manual the definitions of those two types of communications but really I am facing a problem in understanding some paragraphs so I need your help.

those tow  definitions  are for PHP manual:

SOCK_STREAM  **Provides sequenced, reliable, full-duplex, connection-based byte streams**. An out-of-band data transmission mechanism may be supported. The TCP protocol is based on this socket type.

SOCK_SEQPACKET   **Provides a sequenced, reliable, two-way connection-based data transmission path for datagrams of fixed maximum length**; a consumer is required to read an entire packet with each read call.

but really I cant understand why it used the words **full-duplex, connection-based byte streams** and **two-way connection-based data transmission path for datagrams of fixed maximum length** and really I do not know what is the difference between the ***two-way*** connection and the ***full-duplex*** connection.

I am a little confused so I need your help.
Thanks every body.

Answer (score 5):

full-duplex means that it is capable of *simultaneous* communication for sending and receiving data.

The manual is misleading here though; socket types make no guarantee on the efficiency of the communication, but merely what sorts of operations may be performed on them.

From my `socket(2)` manpage:

```
   SOCK_STREAM     Provides sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based byte streams.  An out-of-band  data  transmission
                   mechanism may be supported.

   SOCK_SEQPACKET  Provides  a  sequenced,  reliable, two-way connection-based data transmission path for datagrams of fixed
                   maximum length; a consumer is required to read an entire packet with each input system call.
```

Comment: but what does **two-way** mean.

Comment: Some socket types only allow sending or receiving, not both